# can access to a view be controlled by access to a referenced table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Table_A` and a view `View_A` that is a select of the contents of `Table_A`.

If I deny `SELECT` on `Table_A` to a user, the user can still use the view `View_A`.

Is there a way that I can force the view to return an error when the user tries to use it?

The real world case here is a database with about 20 tables and hundreds of views.  User access is logically tied to the tables so we are hoping to stop folks from using the views based on those tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the views a different owner than the tables so that [the ownership chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is broken and the permissions are checked on the base objects.

Comment: Perfect, Martin - I knew there'd be some way to get around it!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

One of the advantages of views is that you can restrict access to base tables, but grant access via views.  Sound like your system has it backwards.

You are going to have to deny user's access to the views.

Comment: +1 this is one of the selling points of views; I need to know if there's a work-around to force it in the other way...